# Remove element from list and store it in variable?

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

In many programming languages there are functions that remove an element from a set while giving back that element. E.g. I'd like to have a function `FetchFromStack` that does the following:

```
stack = {one, two, three};
element = FetchFromStack[stack]
stack
```

> `one`
>
> `{two, three}`

Of course I can implement it like:

```
If[stack==={}, element=False, element = stack[[1]]]
If[Length[stack]>1, stack = stack[[2;;]], stack={} ]
```

but this seems much too hacky of a solution to me. Is there a proper routine in Mathematica that does this? If not, what would be the best way to implement it?

Comment: Should there be any output if `stack == {}`?

Comment: @march good point! In that case `fetchFromStack` should return `False`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
push[stackID_][e_] := Last[$Stack[stackID] = {$Stack[stackID], e}]

pop[stackID_] := Replace[$Stack[stackID],
    {
    {s_, e_} :> ($Stack[stackID] = s; e),
    _ -> Missing["Empty"]
    }
]

stack[stackID_] := $Stack[stackID]

empty[stackID_] := Quiet[Unset@$Stack[stackID];, Unset::norep]

$Stack[_]={};
```

For example, push 1 through 5 to stack id 1:

```
push[1] /@ Range[5]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

Then, pop 6 elements from stack id 1:

```
Table[pop[1], {6}]
```

> {5, 4, 3, 2, 1, Missing["Empty"]}

Note that the stack is implemented as a nested list instead of a flat list for efficiency reasons. So:

```
empty[1]
push[1] /@ Range[3];
stack[1]
```

> {{{{}, 1}, 2}, 3}

Changing the implementation to a flat list is simple, although you will take a performance hit for long stacks ($O(n)$ vs $O(1)$).

Comment: Is there a way to read out each stack without adding or removing anything?

Comment: I see, so the stack is nested. But how exactly does that contribute to efficiency?

Comment: What would make an unnested stack slower compared to this? Doesn't adding or removing an element require the whole list to be moved in memory and be rewritten either way?

Comment: I couldn't find a good question/answer discussing why `Append`/`AppendTo` is bad, but the short answer is that `AppendTo[list, elem]` makes a copy of list (hence $O(n)$) while `list = {list, elem}` does not (hence $O(1)$).

Comment: This is huge! I did not know that. Is it true that `list=list[[1]]` does not make a copy of anything either? Then the stack should be unloaded in reverse, to improve performance. And I think that is exactly what your code does.

Comment: @Kagaratsch. For more on this "linked-list" structure, see the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25474/29734).

Comment: Is there a quick way to get the number of elements on the stack? I figure `stack[1]//Flatten//Length` won't do in terms of performance, and `Depth[stack[1]]` goes after the depth in the elements as well as the stack.

Comment: @Kagaratsch If you need this I think you could add a counter, and increment/decrement it in the definition of push/pop.

Comment: I've taken this idea, combined with a few others, fleshed it out with some more functions, and created a package. The StackLength function is unfortunately crude, so don't use it too frequently. Package is at https://github.com/truculentmath/QueueStack

Answer (score 5):

Here is one possible implementation that is somewhat *Mathematica*-idiomatic.  Using your list:

```
stack = {one, two, three};

ClearAll@fetchFromStack
Attributes[fetchFromStack] = HoldAll
fetchFromStack[stack_Symbol /; Evaluate[stack] === {}] := (stack = {};False)
fetchFromStack[stack_Symbol : {elem_}] := (stack = {}; elem)
fetchFromStack[stack_Symbol] := Module[{x = stack[[1]]},
  stack = stack[[2 ;;]];
  x
 ]
```

Then:

```
stack = {one, two, three};
Table[{fetchFromStack[stack], stack}, {5}]
(* {{one, {two, three}}, {two, {three}}, {three, {}}, {False, {}}, {False, {}}} *)
```

Comment: @Kagaratsch. Thanks, but that accept was too fast! I feel like this question could get a lot of attention and have some really good answers, and it won't get as much attention if there's an accept on it!

Comment: OK, removed it for now. :) Will put it back tomorrow, if no one shows up with a different implementation that does this orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: The problem with this approach is if you have two stacks, `stack1` and `stack2`, and you try something like: `curStack = stack1; fetchFromStack[curStack]` it won't work.

Comment: @CarlWoll. I'm not sure I follow, so I might not understand something about how "stack"s are supposed to be interact. If `stack1 = {one, two, three}`, and we run `curStack = stack1;`, then the definition `curStack = {one, two, three}` is associated with `curStack`, and it gets updated using `fetchFromStack` as normal. Is the problem that `fetchFromStack[currStack]` won't update `stack1`? Is that the desired functionality?

Comment: Right, I think `stack1` should get updated.

Comment: @CarlWoll. I don't think there's an obvious way to fix my answer to have that functionality. Your answer is nice.

Answer (score 5):

One more:

```
ClearAll[fetch];
SetAttributes[fetch, HoldFirst];
fetch[stack_Symbol] := If[Length[stack] > 0,
  Module[{h}, {{h}, stack} = TakeDrop[stack, 1]; h],
  False
]
```

Now

```
stack = {one, two, three};
fetch[stack]
fetch[stack]
fetch[stack]
fetch[stack]
(* one *)
(* two *)
(* three *)
(* False *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[fetch]
stack={one,two,three};
fetch[stack_List/;stack =!= {}]:={First@stack,Rest@stack}
fetch[stack_List]:={{},{}};
```

And now

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The first definition could also be written as

```
 fetch[stack_List /; Length@stack > 0] := {First@stack, Rest@stack}
```

Comment: `TakeDrop[stack, 1]` also works here

Comment: @swish good point. But one needs a check for empty stack. Always too many ways to do the same in Mathematica :)

Answer (score 3):

I was thinking of how to not explicitly check for empty set case, that's what I came up with:

```
SetAttributes[fetchFromStack, HoldFirst];
fetchFromStack[stack_] := Module[{pop},
  {stack, pop} = Reap@ReplacePart[stack, 1 :> (Sow[First@stack]; Nothing)];
  FirstCase[pop, {x_} :> x, False]
  ]

stack = {one, two, three}
fetchFromStack[stack]
fetchFromStack[stack]
fetchFromStack[stack]
fetchFromStack[stack]
(*one, two, three, False*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SetAttributes[fetch, HoldFirst];
fetch[s_ /; Length@s > 0] := With[{o = First@s}, s = Rest@s; o]
fetch[_] := False

stack = {1, 2, 3, 4};

Table[{fetch@stack, stack}, {Length@stack + 1}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Does this mean, even though `s` is an internal variable of routine `fetch`, it still saves its changes (`s = Rest@s;`) into the outside list `stack` that was passed to it? Isn't that kind of weird?

Comment: Because of `HoldFirst` `s` becomes `stack` (passed by reference)

Comment: I see, that's very handy!

Answer (score 3):

New with Mathematica 12.1, you can use the ["Queue"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/datastructure/Queue.html) [`DataStructure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataStructure). For your example:

```
ds = CreateDataStructure["Queue"];
ds["Push", #]& /@ {one, two, three};
```

Then, the elements are:

```
ds["Elements"]
```

> {one, two, three}

Pop the first element:

```
ds["Pop"]
```

> one

The queue now only has two elements:

```
ds["Elements"]
```

> {two, three}

You can also query the length of the queue with:

```
ds["Length"]
```

> 2

or only peek at the first element with:

```
ds["Peek"]
ds["Elements"]
```

> two

> {two, three}